List.accumulate invalid identifier
I'm using power query to replace value in a table
    Replacements = [
    {"1400", "Site Prep"}, {"1500", "Instrum & Telecom"}, {"1600", "Elec"}, {"1700", "Civil"},
   {"1800", "Structure"}, {"2000", "Bldg"}, {"2200", "Insulation"}, {"2300", "Painting"}
],
ReplacedValues = List.Accumulate(Replacements, RemovedColumns, (current, state) => 
    Table.ReplaceValue(current, state{0}, state{1}, Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Tag Discipline", "Discipline", "Phase", "Inspection state"})
),

I'm having a invalid identifier error just after =[
And finally :
I'm not sure what is happening and can not find any info.
Thanks four your support
N.



You are conflating records and lists. You could use Replacements = {  {"1400", "Site Prep"}, {"1500", "Instrum & Telecom"}, {"1600", "Elec"}, {"1700", "Civil"},    {"1800", "Structure"}, {"2000", "Bldg"}, {"2200", "Insulation"}, {"2300", "Painting"} } to create a list of lists.

Try this to replace values across all columns using a record list
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source),each {_, type text})),
Replacements = [1400="Site Prep", 1500="Instrum & Telecom", 1600="Elec", 1700="Civil",1800="Structure",2000="Bldg",2200="Insulation",2300="Painting"],
Replace=Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",Replacements,"something",(x,y,z)=>try Record.FieldOrDefault(y,x,x) otherwise null,  Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in Replace


